# SBT build failing by not finding scala jar dependecies

Tags: sbt

My SBT build is failing at compile.
I have the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Tetst Advice Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
```

And I do have this:

```
~\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.6
```

So clearly I have the right version of Scala installed for my SBT.
My SBT version is `0.13`.

When it tries to compile the code I get this error:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in [x].class refers to term runtime
[error] in package scala.reflect which is not available.
```

What it seems to me is that the SBT build is not picking up the Scala libraries.

Note that all my dependency jars are placed under the `lib` folder and I am not downloading them using `libraryDependencies`.

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the Scala version you have actually includes the *specific* thing you're referencing in your `x.class`. Without that code, I can't say what you're trying to utilize, but use `scala.util.Properties.scalaPropOrElse("version.number", "unknown")` to determine what version of Scala is *actually* being used. Use println or your logging to output the result from that call.

Then reference that version number to the Scala API and verify that what you're calling is *actually* there. Without more information I can't directly answer this for you. But you need to positively confirm that the version of Scala being used by your runtime code actually does contain the object or class you're attempting to reference in your file.

Note that simply having a Scala directory in your `.sbt` directory doesn't guarantee that it is using that build. To verify the SBT scala Version, put this at the bottom of your `build.sbt` file:

```
val x = {
  println("Scala version: " + scala.util.Properties.scalaPropOrElse("version.number", "unknown") )
  Seq("")
}
```

This will display what Scala version you're actually using in the SBT file. This may not necessarily be the `2.10.6` in your `.sbt`.

Comment: When I dynamically download the dependencies it works fine. I suppose placing all the static dependencies under a lib folder is a challenge.

Comment: Maybe I missed something: specifically what dependency needs to be downloaded to fix your problem? You can have some managed and some unmanaged dependencies. The former is a lot easier to handle.

Comment: The issue I get is with package scala.reflect not getting found during compile time.
In my lib folder I have some jars which inturn need scala libraries. I assumed that since scala libs are part of scala installation the compile task would always find them.
When this did not work I simply used libraryDependencies to download my dependencies and it downloaded all and compile worked fine.

I still think if you need to provide static dependencies, compile task should atleast find scala ones and not make us add those to lib folder.

Comment: @SachinMittal I agree: I think that, probably, you're not finding them because SBT is built against an increasingly old version of Scala and has not been updated in a few years. But I can't directly reproduce, so maybe that assessment is wrong.